# Minimum Maximum Month of datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am having two month and year picker using jquery ui datepicker i want to restrict second month and year picker will be select only after the month and year of first date picker i don't know it is possible or not please give me guidance if possible my script as below

```
<script>
$(document).ready(
    function () {
      $( "#date1_in_id" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,//this option for allowing user to select month
        changeYear: true, //this option for allowing user to select from year range
        dateFormat: "mm-yy",
        showButtonPanel: true,
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
       }

      });
       $( "#date2_in_id" ).datepicker({
         changeMonth: true,//this option for allowing user to select month
        changeYear: true, //this option for allowing user to select from year range
        dateFormat: "mm-yy",           
        showButtonPanel: true,
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
       }            
      });

    });

</script>
<style>.ui-datepicker-calendar{display: none;}</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **minDate** and  **maxDate** to set a minimum or maximum date.

More information here: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

Comment: i want to restrict month and year

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can with this script, the person needs to choose the first datepicker and after that the second datpicker can be choosen after the date of the first one.

Replace onClose of this one first $( "#date1_in_id" ):

```
     onClose: function( selectedDate ) {

        lafecha = selectedDate.split('-');
        fecha_alreves = lafecha[2]+'-'+lafecha[1]+'-'+lafecha[0];


        fecha = new Date(fecha_alreves);

        ayer = new Date(fecha);
        ayer.setTime(ayer.getTime() - 1000*60*60*24);
        dias = ayer.getDate();
        dias += 01;
        dia = ayer.getDay() + 1;
        mes = ayer.getMonth() + 1;
        anno = ayer.getFullYear() + 1;
        nuevafecha = mes+"-"+dias+"-"+anno;

        $( "#date2_in_id" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        $( "#date2_in_id" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", nuevafecha );
    }
```

Then replace the onClose of this one $( "#date2_in_id" )

```
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#date1_in_id" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
    }
```

I hope that works for you

Comment: it is for date restriction i want restrict month and year only i am using like 01-2015